# Missing data in response body

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fastapi

I have a web service(FastAPI) deployed on AWS EC2.

In java client code, when I call the api, i got this error

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 3,849,324; received: 1,834,837)
```

In postman, when I call this api, the response is returned but not enough like this image
[image]

Seem the server (Fast API web service) do not return all data in response body.

I already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152816/premature-end-of-content-length-delimited-message-body-expected) question, the accepted answer said that this error is belong server-side.

So what is the problem here? What can I configure to solve this problem, on the AWS or my web service or any ?

Additional information, in the API implementation, business logic is connect to the AWS S3 and download some files. I don't know if this is the problem but when I looked for solution, a lot of people said it related to AWS S3

Thank you all guys!!!

Comment: The problem is that server sent a response stating that response length is `3,849,324` bytes in the header, but actual payload was only `1,834,837` bytes after which the server closed the connection - at least that's what I understand.

Comment: Oh I understand that too. But it has no meaning, lol. I don't know why this happened then I can't fix this

Comment: You need to check server side.

Comment: Did you check if you are returning the response before filling up the response data? May be a timing issue? You can test the below thing.  Support your data are stored in B then, first of all, log that data in somewhere like in cloud log and then return it.  so that you can trace that data.

Comment: It can be a latency & time-out issue. Check for S3's region for latency and the time-out. Or maybe, you can try to get values in batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several investigating hours. My leader found the issue, it's not an out of memory issue. It is out of Hard disk driver instead of RAM. Lol

Comment: Please explain it in more detail. So others can be benefited from that.